# How to change customer address frontend validation rules?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-address

I have a question, How to change rules for customer address validation form ?

I found backend validation rules in `Magento_Customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml`, but I can't find frontend javascript rules

Answer (score 1):

Template which is used for customer form address changes:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/address.phtml
```

Helper which is used to get the validation class:

```
\Mage_Customer_Helper_Address::getAttributeValidationClass
```

And the validation classes are defined here, with behaviour and validation:

```
js/prototype/validation.js:414
```